# Flutter get_it - Register multiple APIs in repo

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dio

I am using [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) in My Flutter App. I have registered singletons for network request using [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Now I want to use multiple base urls in dio requests so I have to create multiple instances for dio.

For that I have to register it once again in get_it. Its giving me an error while registering same types of singletons in get_it repo.

What I have done:
I have added two Dio Clients for two different APIs
I have add these two lines for registering Dio Clients in GetIt.

**First API (Dio Client)**

```
_getIt.registerSingleton<Dio>(DioClient().getDio());
```

**Second API (Dio Client)**

```
_getIt.registerSingleton<Dio>(DioAnotherClient().getDio());
```

I am Facing this error after doing this:

> E/flutter (13845): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]
> Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Object/factory with  type
> Dio is already registered inside GetIt.

I am seeking a solution to Use Multiple APIs using GetIt & Dio Package.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you figured it out? If yes could you share your solution? One idea I have is using single class with baseUrl as parameter and define things in constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple instances of the same class in getIt when you pass an instanceName when registering:

```
    // First API (Dio Client)
_getIt.registerSingleton(DioClient().getDio(), instanceName: "first");

    // Second API (Dio Client)
_getIt.registerSingleton(DioAnotherClient().getDio(), instanceName: "second");

final Dio client = _getIt.get(instanceName: "first");
```